# Opening an existing TFS query via powershell/nuget console

Tags: powershell, tfs

How would one go about opening an existing TFS query using powershell, more specifically the nuget console in VS (2013)?

I have to open several queries each time I open VS, and it would make life much easier to do so via a simple powershell cmdlet.

Thanks!

-k

Answer (score 1):

Please check the post [here](http://juliankay.com/development/querying-tfs-with-tfpt-exe-and-powershell/) which uses tfpt.exe inside powershell scripts to run the TFS queries.

Comment: I've been able to get queries to run via tfpt but its output is simply text on the console.  I want to open a window in VS containing the results of the query, just as if I'd opened them from Team Explorer.